# In accordion component, I want to give table header just 1 time

Tags: react-native

*I give table header to accordion rendercontents. Normally it renders how many items there are in array, so it gives me  headerS as much as array lenght.*

*But i want to have header just 1 time.  How can I do  that ?*

*this is my render :*

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{}}>
          <Accordion
            activeSections={this.state.activeSections}         
            sections={CONTENT2}    
            touchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
            expandMultiple={false}           
            renderHeader={this.renderHeader}           
            renderContent={this.renderContent}           
            duration={400}           
            onChange={this.setSections}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

*this is renderContent:*

```
renderContent(section, _, isActive) {
  const tablehead = ['Beyanname','Gümrük','Saat'];
    return (
      <Animatable.View
        duration={200}
        style={[styles.content, isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive]}
        transition="backgroundColor"
      >
        {section.subcategory.map((item, key) => (
          <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('Id: ' + item.id + ' val: ' + item.val)}>
               <View style={styles.container2}>
     -------->   <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
                   <Row data={tablehead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>      
                 </Table>
               </View>                 
             </TouchableOpacity>
           <View style={styles.separator} />
          </View>
        ))}
      </Animatable.View>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you want it to render? There are 3 items in your `tablehead` array.

Comment: sections={CONTENT2}  here Content2 has 5 items. So  render()  renders 5 times.  when it renders 5 times, renderContent renders 5 times as well. So  I get 5 times header. But i want to give just 1 header row

Comment: post your `Accordion` code

Comment: i post on top man. it is in render

Comment: The actual code of `Accordion`, not how you render it.

Comment: it is ready component bro, CONTENT2 has 5 items so it renders 5 times just this.